# Error when starting an application compiled with static linking of libraries in release mode

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, release, qmake

The launch and operation of my application are possible and successful when compiled in debug mode. Also, the build in release mode does not give any errors.

```
21:45:27: Launch: "D:\TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j4
D:\TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\qt\5.12.7\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile ..\B\B.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler"
D:/TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT/qt/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/**/Desktop/gl/2/BattleShips/build-B-Desktop_Qt_5_12_7_MinGW_64_bit-Release'
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/**/Desktop/**/2/BattleShips/build-B-Desktop_Qt_5_12_7_MinGW_64_bit-Release'
21:45:29: Process"D:\TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT\qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" ended normally.
21:45:29: Time has passed: 00:02.
```

I focus on:

```
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
```

What is it and what does it do ?

But when I run the (pseudo-) builded application, I get:

```
21:25:57: Starting C:\Users\**\Desktop\**\2\BattleShips\build-B-Desktop_Qt_5_12_7_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\B.exe ...
21:25:57: The process was ended forcefully.
21:25:57: C:\Users\**\Desktop\**\2\BattleShips\build-B-Desktop_Qt_5_12_7_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\B.exe crashed.
```

when I try to run the builded application manually from the explorer, I get typical link errors (as if dynamic linking of libraries was used)

```
Qt5core.dll can not be found
```

and the other about the lack of some gcc libraries.

I suppose there is something wrong with my .pro file. 
Here is it:

```
static {
    CONFIG += static
    QT += core gui network widgets
    DEFINES += STATIC
    message("Static build.")
}
CONFIG +=  static -std=c++2a

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    battlefield.cpp \
    image.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    player.cpp \
    server.cpp \
    window.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

FORMS += \
    window.ui

HEADERS += \
    includes.h \
    player.h \
    window.h
```

Ide : windows 10 +  qt 5.12.0 + mingw7.3.0 64 bit provided with qt.

Any suggestions how to build and launch this application properly?

Answer (score 0):

2 things: the Qt files need to be in the `PATH` and Qt must be able to find its plugins.

You could launch a Command Prompt and run this:

```
SET PATH=<qt_path>\bin:$PATH
SET QT_PLUGIN_PATH=<qt_path>\plugins
```

before running your compiled `.exe` from that same Command Prompt.